# In Node + Postgres, when is the proper time to close a pool?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, memory-leaks

I have an app that uses the [pooling](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling) feature of the `node-postgres` package. What I don't understand is when it's necessary to explicitly [shut down](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling#shutdown) a pool via `pool.end()`. My app is simple, only making a single query as noted in [this section](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling#single-query) of the docs.

Right now, my code looks like this. The pool is created once in a separate CJS module and is never shut down.

```
// db.js
const pg = require('pg');

/**
  As soon as the Node server starts, the pool is created and
  remains open for as long as the app is running
*/
const pool = new pg.Pool(SOME_CONFIG);

module.exports = pool;


// routes.js
const db = require('./db');

router.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
  db.query(SOME_QUERY)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      // I do NOT do `db.end()` or anything here because then the app wouldn't work after a single query
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

What I'm wondering, though, is if the pool should be explicitly created every time it's needed and then closed after every query:

```
// query.js
const pg = require('pg');

router.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
  // create new pool every time
  const db = new pg.Pool(SOME_CONFIG);

  db.query(SOME_QUERY)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      db.end(); // close pool every time
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

My goal is simply to avoid memory leaks. If you couldn't tell already, I'm a rookie at this kind of thing. And my question could of course be generalized to other tech, as well. I just don't understand when exactly it's necessary to shut down a DB pool.

Comment: Check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), and you won't need to use the pool directly.